# Updating Chrubuntu 14.04 kernel on Acer C7 (currently 3.4.0)

Tags: ubuntu, script, updates, kernel, chromebook

There was another, similar question on this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/583269/chrubuntu-acer-how-to-load-kernel-3-8-0-16-instead-3-4-0), but it's for old ubuntu versions, and the script no longer works.

While installing, the script works fine until:

`+ vbutil_kernel --verify /dev/sda6 --verbose
+ tail -1
+ sed -e s/$/ disablevmx=off/ /config-2013-05-22-2259-orig.txt
+ vbutil_kernel --pack /newkernel --keyblock /usr/share/vboot/devkeys/kernel.keyblock --version 1 --signprivate /usr/share/vboot/devkeys/kernel_data_key.vbprivk --config=/config-2013-05-22-2259.txt --vmlinuz /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0 --arch x86_64
ERROR: Error reading kernel file.
+ vbutil_kernel --verify /newkernel
ERROR: Unable to stat /newkernel: No such file or directory
+ dd if=/newkernel of=/dev/sda6
dd: opening ‘/newkernel’: No such file or directory`

So the problem is that this /newkernel is called, but it hasn't been created by the script, which apparently wasn't a problem in the past.

Comments on the [original website](http://velvet-underscore.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/chrubuntu-virtualbox-with-kvm.html?showComment=1369260137472#c3032966054980272843) for the script mention the same problem, as well as a solution for 14.04. Unfortunately, I'm a complete novice at this stuff and don't fully understand how to implement the solution:

> Just a quick note, I used the 3.8 version of the script to get a kernel working on a chrubutu Acer to match the video demands of 14.04. Had to get old_bins in place, like this:
>
> `mount -o ro /dev/sda3 /mnt
>   cd /usr/bin
>   cp -a /mnt/usr/bin/old_bins/`
>
> And in kernel_next/Makefile comment out the halt-on-warning instruction:
>
> `# KBUILD_CFLAGS += -Werror`
>
> and to KBUILD_CFLAGS add:
>
> `-fno-tree-vrp`
>
> and ended up with a 3.8.11 kernel that's working well.

So I guess this is a request. Can someone update the script with the necessary changes, or describe in greater detail what needs to be done?

Comment: After getting the script working and finding the new kernel incompatible, I've read that the easiest way to do this is to update the kernel in ChromeOS and then install Chrubuntu, copying over the kernel in the process. This too, however, has hit a snag. I'll put it in a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't own a chromebook but I'm a linux user so...

```
mount -o ro /dev/sda3 /mnt
cd /usr/bin
cp -a /mnt/usr/bin/ old_bins/
```

These are commands that are executed on a terminal emulator, just open one and login as `root` with the `su` command and issue them afterwards. (the `#` sign in a shell indicates that you're executing commands as the `root` user).

```
$ su
<enter your root password>
# mount -o ro /dev/sda3 /mnt
# cd /usr/bin
# cp -a /mnt/usr/bin/ old_bins/
```

I assume the `old_bins/` part is separated from the rest, as the `cp` command needs minimum 2 params to work. What it does is to copy the `/mnt/usr/bin/` directory (and its contents) to the `old_bins/` directory (which will end up inside `/usr/bin` not `/mnt/usr/bin`).

And I assumme you have access to this file `kernel_next/Makefile` which is a `makefile` inside a directory named `kernel_next`. So you have to open it with your preferred text editor and add a `#` sign (it means "comment the following line" in many languages) before the line `KBUILD_CFLAGS += -Werror`. Like this:

**Before**

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS += -Werror
```

**After**

```
# KBUILD_CFLAGS += -Werror
```

And just afterwards add the `-fno-tree-vrp` flag to the `KBUILD_CFLAGS` statement, like this: `KBUILD_CFLAGS += -fno-tree-vrp`. You'll end up with something like this in your makefile:

```
# KBUILD_CFLAGS += -Werror
KBUILD_CFLAGS += -fno-tree-vrp
```

Then you can proceed to do whatever you were doing. Good luck.

Comment: This was very helpful for making the changes suggested in the post. It didn't work for installing the kernel, however - it just didn't boot after I ran the script. The actual problem was the script is that I needed to update the vmlinuz to the one that comes with 14.04. Once I did that, the script ran, but like I say it didn't seem compatible.